# Can I get list of classes from `torchvision.datasets.ImageNet` without downloading dataset?

Tags: pytorch, imagenet

It looks like until recently there were no such list in `pytorch` (see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/713)). Now we have `ImageNet` class in `torchvision` but it's not quite clear how can I get list of classes.